# Building a new column in a pandas dataframe by matching string values in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, replace, nested-loops

I am trying to build a new column, `NewCol4`, in a pandas dataframe based on another column, `SearchCol3`, already in the dataframe.  Each value of `SearchCol3` is tested to see if it contains any of the sub-strings in the list `stings`.  If the value in `SearchCol3` contains one of the sub-strings in the list `strings` then the corresponding value in the list `replacement` is inserted into the column `NewCol4` of the same row the sub-string was found in.  If no sub-string is found in a value of `SearchCol3` then the value from `Col2` is inserted into `NewCol4`.

Desired results:

```
    Col1  Col2    SearchCol3   NewCol4
0   20    'May'   'abc(feb)'   'February'
1   30    'March' 'def | mar'  'March'
2   40    'June'  'ghi | feb'  'February'
3   50    'July'  'jkl(apr)'   'April'
4   60    'May'   'mno(mar)'   'March'
5   70    'March' 'abc'        'March'
```

Currently I am using this code for the job.

```
strings = ['jan',
           'feb',
           'mar',
           'apr',
           'may']

replacement = ['January',
               'Febuary',
               'March',
               'April',
               'May']


data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

data['NewCol4'] = ''

for j in range(len(strings)):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if strings[j] in data.SearchCol3[i]:
            data.NewCol4[i] = replacement[j]


for i in range(len(data)):
    if data.NewCol4[i] == '':
        data.NewCol4[i] = data.Col2[i]
```

My data, search, and replacement dataframe and lists are much longer than in this example.  I am looking for something more efficient than what I am currently using to try to save time.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, and on the plus side, is very readable!

```
strings = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may']
replacement = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']

def match_string(col3, col2):
    # if in col3, return that result. Else, lazy eval for col2. If neither, return empty string.
    k = ([replacement[strings.index(s)] for s in strings if s in col3]) or ([s for s in replacement if s in col2])
    return k[0] if k else ''

df['NewCol4'] = df.apply(lambda x: match_string(x['SearchCol3'], x['Col2']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Col2 SearchCol3   NewCol4
0    May   abc(feb)  February
1  March  def | mar     March
2   June  ghi | feb  February
3   July   jkl(apr)     April
4    May   mno(mar)     March
5  March        abc     March
```

Answer (score 1):

.str.extract accepts a regex.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Col1': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
        'Col2': ['May','March','June','July','May','March'],
        'SearchCol3': ['abc(feb)','def | mar','ghi | feb','jkl(apr)','mno(mar)','abc']})


a_regex = '(jan|feb|mar|apr|may)'
month_replacements = {'jan': 'January','feb': 'February',
            'mar': 'March','apr': 'April','may': 'May'}

#Extract Using Regex
df['NewCol4'] = df['SearchCol3'].str.extract(a_regex).fillna('')
#Look up values from dictionary
df['NewCol4'] = df['NewCol4'].apply(lambda x: month_replacements.get(x,''))
#Use default value from other coumn if no other value
df['NewCol4'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Col2'] if row['NewCol4'] == '' else row['NewCol4'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Col1   Col2 SearchCol3   NewCol4
0    20    May   abc(feb)  February
1    30  March  def | mar     March
2    40   June  ghi | feb  February
3    50   July   jkl(apr)     April
4    60    May   mno(mar)     March
5    70  March        abc     March
```

Comment: A much better approach than mine. +1

Comment: Thanks, that was much faster than what I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many equivalent ways to accomplish this task and it looks like a useful test-case to better understand Pandas' performance in general, I ran a benchmark on all the submitted answers (I am the author of the code in cells #3,  #4, #7 and #10).

I increased the input data size thousand-fold for a more realistic and fair comparison – otherwise the pure-Python solutions outperform Pandas-based methods due to a constant overhead that becomes irrelevant for large datasets. The solutions are sorted best-to-worst.

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
                   'Col2': ['May', 'March', 'June', 'July', 'May', 'March'],
                   'SearchCol3': ['abc(feb)', 'def | mar', 'ghi | feb', 'jkl(apr)', 'mno(mar)', 'abc']})

strings = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may']
replacement = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']

mapping = dict(zip(strings, replacement))

a_regex = '(jan|feb|mar|apr|may)'
month_replacements = {'jan': 'January','feb': 'February',
            'mar': 'March','apr': 'April','may': 'May'}


In [2]:
# Use a more realistic input size
df['NewCol4'] = ''
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index().consolidate()


In [3]:
%%timeit -n 100
result = []
for searchcol, default in zip(df["SearchCol3"], df["Col2"]):
    for s in mapping:
        if s in searchcol:
            result.append(mapping[s])
            break
    else:
        result.append(default)
df['NewCol4'] = result
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop


In [4]:
%%timeit -n 100
result = []
for index, searchcol, default in df[["SearchCol3", "Col2"]].itertuples():
    for s in mapping:
        if s in searchcol:
            result.append(mapping[s])
            break
    else:
        result.append(default)
df['NewCol4'] = result
100 loops, best of 3: 8.64 ms per loop


In [5]:
%%timeit -n 100
df['NewCol4'] = df.Col2
for i, s in enumerate(strings):
    df.loc[df.SearchCol3.str.contains(s), 'NewCol4'] = replacement[i]
100 loops, best of 3: 23.1 ms per loop


In [6]:
100
%%timeit -n 100
df['NewCol4'] = None
# Use month name if abbreviation in `SearchCol3`.
for month_code, month in zip(strings, replacement):
    df.loc[df.SearchCol3.str.contains(month_code), 'NewCol4'] = month
# Create a mask of null values and apply Col2 if null.
mask = df.NewCol4.isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'NewCol4'] = df.loc[mask, 'Col2']
100 loops, best of 3: 24.4 ms per loop


In [7]:
%%timeit -n 100
def match_string(searchcol, default):
    for s in mapping:
        if s in searchcol:
            return mapping[s]
    return default
​
df['NewCol4'] = df.apply(lambda x: match_string(x['SearchCol3'], x['Col2']), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop


In [8]:
%%timeit -n 100
def match_string(col3, col2):
    k = ([s for s in strings if s in col3])
    if k:  # if found in col3, return that result
        return replacement[strings.index(k[0])]
    l = ([s for s in replacement if s in col2])
    if l:  # else if found in col2, return second best option
        return l[0]
    return ''  # if neither, return empty string
df['NewCol4'] = df.apply(lambda x: match_string(x['SearchCol3'], x['Col2']), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 144 ms per loop


In [9]:
%%timeit -n 100
#Extract Using Regex
df['NewCol4'] = df['SearchCol3'].str.extract(a_regex).fillna('')
#Look up values from dictionary
df['NewCol4'] = df['NewCol4'].apply(lambda x: month_replacements.get(x,''))
#Use default value from other coumn if no other value
df['NewCol4'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Col2'] if row['NewCol4'] == '' else row['NewCol4'], axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 147 ms per loop


In [10]:
%%timeit -n 10
df['NewCol4'] = ''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    searchcol = row["SearchCol3"]
    for s in mapping:
        if s in searchcol:
            df.loc[index, "NewCol4"] = mapping[s]
            break
    else:
        df.loc[index, "NewCol4"] = row["Col2"]
10 loops, best of 3: 2.82 s per loop
```

Comment: +1 for the effort. Also, does this mean I coded something that's both fast _and_ readable? Wow. Today was a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```
data['NewCol4'] = data.Col2
for i,s in enumerate(strings):
    data.loc[data.SearchCol3.str.contains(s),'NewCol4']=replacement[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are typically the fastest for munging Dataframe object dtypes. Heres a one line list comprehension formatted for readability:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Col1': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
    'Col2': ['May','March','June','July','May','March'],
    'SearchCol3': ['abc(feb)','def | mar','ghi | feb','jkl(apr)','mno(mar)','abc']})

df['NewCol4'] = ['January' if 'jan' in x else
                 'Febuary' if 'feb' in x else
                 'March'   if 'mar' in x else
                 'April'   if 'apr' in x else
                 'May'     if 'may' in x else
                 x for x in df['SearchCol3']]
```

Output:

```
    Col1    Col2    SearchCol3  NewCol4
 0  20      May     abc(feb)    Febuary
 1  30      March   def | mar   March
 2  40      June    ghi | feb   Febuary
 3  50      July    jkl(apr)    April
 4  60      May     mno(mar)    March
 5  70      March   abc         abc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initial data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70],
                   'Col2': ['May', 'March', 'June', 'July', 'May', 'March'],
                   'SearchCol3': ['abc(feb)', 'def | mar', 'ghi | feb', 'jkl(apr)', 'mno(mar)', 'abc']})

strings = ['jan',
           'feb',
           'mar',
           'apr',
           'may']

replacement = ['January',
               'Febuary',
               'March',
               'April',
               'May']

# Set new column values to None.
df['NewCol4'] = None

# Use month name if abbreviation in `SearchCol3`.
for month_code, month in zip(strings, replacement):
    df.loc[df.SearchCol3.str.contains(month_code), 'NewCol4'] = month

# Create a mask of null values and apply Col2 if null.
mask = df.NewCol4.isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'NewCol4'] = df.loc[mask, 'Col2']

# Voila!
>>> df
   Col1   Col2 SearchCol3  NewCol4
0    20    May   abc(feb)  Febuary
1    30  March  def | mar    March
2    40   June  ghi | feb  Febuary
3    50   July   jkl(apr)    April
4    60    May   mno(mar)    March
5    70  March        abc    March
```